# how to improve android programming environment (work environment) e.g. for windows 7

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-juno

Every Android Developer seen problems of eclipse independent of version. It can give errors at time when you are sure that it shouldn't, project can need a lot of clearing for giving you to run it, and a lot of problems like this and more in `xml` editor. Only using last version of eclipse not helping.

So what I need.

*Can anybody give some suggestions how to improve android developing environment, for not getting angry and not losing time nonsensical?*

Thanks in advance and sorry for English

Comment: It's not helping anymore :)

Comment: I like [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) better for any kind of Java Development. But this is a personal opinion!